# How to set keyboard always display on screen?

Tags: android, eclipse, keyboard

I'm trying to make a page in Android, that the keyboard is always display, even when the user is pressing the back button (in that case I would like the app to go back to the last page).
For example: The page that Facebook did when you are writing a post in there app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"` to your activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" />
```

Comment: Thanks for you'r answer. I did, but when I'm pressing the back button the keyboard is disappeared. I want the keyboard to stay display no matter what.